# What's the best open source alternatives of COMSOL?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, non-linear-systems

Good time of day. I need to solve system of differential non-linear equations for 3D system. It requires parallel computing on a cluster. Our lab lacks the license on Comsol. It is necessary to determine the heat capacity in a disordered system experiencing the glass transition process.
What's the good open-source alternative to install instead of Comsol?

Comment: Hmmmm… when you really need Comsol, there aren’t many real alternatives. Closest for open source is diving into the problem with Python.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because software recommendations are [considered off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3980/25301).

Comment: Also, there's literally a whole website devoted to alternative softwares, aptly called [*AlternativeTo*](https://alternativeto.net), that has several recommendations of alternatives to comsol.

Comment: Kyle Kanos, I found it weird that FreeCad and other CADs were recommended as an alternative to Comsol. I've bothered looking. Your answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using freeFEM, since it is Python based, threading is possible.

Comment: *since it is Python based* Seeing how their documentation page literally says [*FreeFEM is written in C++ and its language is a C++ idiom.*](https://doc.freefem.org/introduction/), I find this claim that it's Python quite odd.